# How to use LINQ to Fill List<string> with column values

Tags: list, linq, combobox

I'm looking for a solution to fill a ComboBox with column values of a LINQ statement.

```cs
List<string> comboList = new List<string>();
```

I have a table with localisation data.

This table looks like

```
ID;Language;Argument1;Argument2;Argument3;Argument4; and so on
```

I want the value of `Argument1;Argument2;Argument3;Argumant4; and so on`.

My simple LINQ expression is:

```cs
var query = (from x in dc.tblListItems
             where x.Language == "English"
             select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

There will be more columns in the future, so I can't select it in the LINQ query directly.

Now I try to fill the `List<string>` for myComboBox with the column values except the first two ones `ID;Language`

```cs
foreach (var item in query)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] fields = query.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var f in fields)
    {
        comboList.Add(f.GetValue(item).ToString());
    }
}
```

But this attempt fail.

I hope you have a solution for me.

Comment: `query` is single object, how do you plan to enumerate object? And why your code fail? Which error do you have?

Comment: And probably instead of `query.GetType()` it should be `item.GetType()`

Comment: Great sugestion! item.GetType() was the nasty little error i made. Now it works.